# BlazeDS/ FLEX - Upload an Image and Display

Tags: java, apache-flex, tomcat, flex4

I'm working on a FLEX which enables the user navigate through a list of images at the server (BalzeDS tomcat 4.0.0.14931). The images stored under the "WebContent/Images", and the already available/ saved images are displayed as desired.

From this app user would be able to select a file from their local directory and upload it. I have done the necessary coding related with uploading the image and it successfully creates a copy at the desired folder at the server. Once the image file is uploaded I'm trying to display the it at the FLEX end, but the image is not displayed. When check at the target folder at the server end, the file has been created successfully.

In order to make the uploaded image visible, the BlazeDS Tomcat server has to be restarted. Since this is not desired way to go ahead, I am seeking some help from you experts out there to resolved this.

I tried searching the net get this issue sorted out, but unable to come cross any solution. An identical issue was posted on another forum ([Tomcat restart problem](http://java.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/java-l/tomcat-restart-problem-image-upload-and-display-it-3290732)), that also still not resolved.

I this is best approach to achieve this JAVA/ BlazeDS/ TomCat/ FLEX environment or is there a better alternative. The other alternative I could achieve this is through persisting the file into the database as byte[], but I did not want accomplish in that manner since size of the database tend to shoot up.

I would really appreciate if you could help me out on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you store the file, I hope not in the web-app direcory? Did you trigger the algotihm that scanns the upload folder and send the list of immages to the client after you stored the immge?

Comment: Well apparently that what I have done, i.e. used the web-app directory to store the files. What do you mean by the algorithm that scans the folder? Can you pls give me some insights on this? Thankx!

Answer (score 1):

If you have to restart Tomcat, that means you are storing user data in your web-apps directory. You should not be storing any user data in the webapps folder. These are considered "system files" and should not be publicly editable under any circumstance.

Store any user data in a publicly accessible folder with the correct permissions and serve them over HTTP (you should be able to view it in a web browser).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. So ideally a separate folder should be made available instead of a folder within the project's web-apps. I was also considering this option, but wouldn't this involve separately hosting such a folder? Is there any possibility to enable HTTP access to a folder using Tomcat itself?

Comment: @fujiFX: you need to implement some additioal servlet to access the files form an directory that is not in the web-app directory.

Comment: Not to sure about that, but I don't see why not. We've always just used Apache for that kind of stuff since it is better optimized for serving static web content (IE. run the web app in Tomcat, serve dynamic media over an HTTP service like Apache).